# As3 email forms php with components

Tags: php, forms, actionscript-3, flash, combobox

I need to create an email form with AS3. Coming from AS2 my knowledge is limited. On stage, i have a submit button, a combobox, and two textinput fields for email and  password. Reading throught some tutorials i know how to send the variables email and password to the mysql database. My question is, in the form i have populated a combobox with some data. How can i send that piece of data to my DB?
I show you my code to see sorry its rather long but if you can help that be great!

```
//Building the variables
var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

//Requesting the php file
var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("php.file");
phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

 phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;

 //Building the loader
 var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

 phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

 //Variables ready for the processing
 phpVars.email = email.text;
 phpVars.password = password.text;

btn_one.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnHandler);

 //Validate form fields
 function btnHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
    statusTxt.text =  "" + event.target.data.systemResult;
    trace(event.target.data.systemResult);
```

}

```
    var statusTxt:TextField = new TextField();
    statusTxt.x = 160.00;
    statusTxt.y = 9.80;
    statusTxt.width = 241.95;
    statusTxt.height = 22.75;
    statusTxt.text = "Please fill out the form below";
    addChild(statusTxt);

    //Wanting to add this combobox to my db
       var persons:Array = new Array();
    persons[0] = "Male";
    persons[1] = "Female";

   combo_box.dataProvider = new DataProvider(persons);
   combo_box.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, dataHandler);

   function dataHandler(e:Event):void{
      trace(e.target.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try AmfPHP. It's perfect for filling the gap between flash and PHP.

You can program your services in php, and debug using the servicebrowser.
Once the php-side is working, you can do the as3 part.

http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/

Has helped me a lot in the past